# Resize image from outside Jquery handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, image-resizing

i try to create image resizer tool using jquery UI.

here is the file : http://jegbagus.com/try/resize.html

when i to resize image using form, jquery UI not directly follow image resize.
how to get both of this method work together. i already read the jquery UI docs. but i don't get any clue.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say resize image in jQuery, do you mean just visually? If yes why not just update the css values for the image height and width? So on change, update size with appropriate values like:

```
 $('img').css('width','200px');
 $('img').css('height','200px');
```

If you want to then resize this image on file, look into PHP image GD functions.